# Make div's height as its content or as its parent if it is smaller

Tags: css, layout, html

Some html:

```
<div style="height: 300px">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="title">
       ...
    </div>
    <div id="content">
       ....
    </div>
    <div>
       ..another div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want my inner div height to be not greater than parent div's and if it is greater then content div should have scroll, but if it is smaller it should be the same size with it's content.

I've tried to set inner's max_height=100%, but I can't make my content have scroll.
I want to do it without js

UPD: I do not know main div's height (300px is not constant)

UPD2: My main div has "max-height: 100%", so I do not know exact value

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/kzfRk/7/

Comment: use the clear:both ; in child div

Comment: Clear? But I have not any float div

Comment: the sugestion of overflow is not working?

Comment: I have to set height and overflow will be enabled after setting height to content

Comment: how you set the height then? variable of language? you cant set the same value on the div inner?

Comment: Just set containers `overflow: auto`

Comment: My main div has "max-height: 100%" property, so I have to do my inner div be the same size, or smaller if content is not big

Answer (score 1):

You set your height then use overflow to control the scrolling.

```
​#inner{max-height:100%;overflow-y:scroll;}​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/drC3L/ Change the size of the outer div to anything you want, if there is too much content the inner div will scroll.

Comment: I can't do it, bcz main div's height is not constant value

Comment: Updated to cover dynamic outer div height.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but if your scroll bars are not appearing try:

```
#inner{overflow-y:scroll;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind? (colours are just for ease of viewing) See live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kzfRk/5/).

### css

```
.container{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#inner{
    max-height:300px;
    overflow-y: auto; border: 1px solid #f00;
}
#title{ background-color: #eed;}
#content{background-color: #fee;}
```

### html

```
<div class='container'>
  <div id="inner"> 
    <div id="title"> 
       ... 
    </div> 
    <div id="content"> 
        ....    
    </div>    
    <div>    
       ..another div    
    </div>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a live example? It's difficult to work out what you are trying to do.

Do you want the parent div to fill the screen and the content to scroll withing it? If so, give your parent div a height of 100% and try applying the following style to your inner div:

```
height:100%; min-height: 100%; overflow:auto;
```

Comment: I don't want my div be greater it's content

Comment: It has to be bigger. If you've set the hieght of .root to 100px and your content doesn't fill 100px, you will end up with a gap.

Comment: Gap is ok! Bcz I have few columns and I do not want them to be the same size

Comment: Then the only way to do it is to have the whole of the inner div scroll. You can't make the content div scroll without giving it a height, and that will create the gap before the footer, instead of after it. Replace your .inner css with .inner {overflow-y: auto; border: 1px solid #f00; height:95px;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the inner div maximum height the same as the root div height.  Using your fiddle, copy and paste the CSS below into your CSS file and it will work...

```
.container{
    max-height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.inner{
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto; border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.root{
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```